# Bootstrap layout media queries not working at 767px on Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have a Chrome-only problem with my Bootstrap (v3.3.5) layout css at exactly 767px where the layout styles simply aren't being applied.

Here's the behaviour after experimenting with the console on 3 browsers...

```
Chrome
-window.innerWidth of <= 766 - correctly shows mobile layout
-window.innerWidth of == 767 - incorrectly applies no layout styles
-window.innerWidth of >= 768 - correctly shows full screen layout

Firefox
-window.innerWidth of <=766 and ==767 - correctly shows mobile layout
-window.innerWidth of >=768 - correctly shows full screen layout

Safari
-behaves fine although window.innerWidth doesn't correctly correspond to the breakpoints (perhaps something to do with Safari not accounting for scrollbars in the same way)
```

All my media queries have been created as follows...

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
/*small view*/
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
/*full view*/
}
```

I've experimented changing these values so there's an overlap (e.g. a min-width of 767px) but it has no effect.

Apologies if this is a little vague, but I don't really know where to go from here in investigating the problem and have found only one report of similar behaviour from a previous version of bootstrap (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1531).

Does anyone know of any possible reason that I'd be seeing this on Chrome only?  Either way, any advice on an appropriate way to investigate would be very much appreciated.

**-- EDIT --**
After hours of research I tested this simple file...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        @media (max-width: 767px) {
            .headlineText {
              font-size: 10px;
              color: red;
            }
        } 
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .headlineText {
              font-size: 10px;
              color: green;
            }
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="headlineText">this is a headline</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

On Chrome only - at 767px the text is neither green or red - it's black, Times New Roman, and considerably bigger than 10px.  Of course I can't replicate this by uploading to a fiddle/codepen - so it must be something to do with the fact I'm running on a localhost (via MAMP).  Absolutely zero ideas why that would be the case, but at least it doesn't seem to be something that will affect me in a live environment

Comment: I just have similar problem and it's very weird, same in Firefox and Chrome broken layout on exactly 767px. What's more weird is that on my friend's computer it works fine and we are both using Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome (for me version 89.0.4389.82 on Win10) seems to work with fraction of pixels. Hence, increasing all lower breakpoint thresholds by .9px solved the issue for me. So for example

`max-width :767px` needs to become `max-width :767.9px`

Answer (score 1):

Make this full screen and resize your window. It works for me in Chrome and has no display of "does not work" in between.

```css
.works {
  display: none;
}
.does-not-work {
  display: block;
}
@media(max-width:767px){
  .works {
    display: block;
  }
  .works::before {
    content: 'max-width: 767px | ';
  }
  .does-not-work {
    display: none;
  }
} 
@media(min-width:768px){
  .works {
    display: block;
  }
  .works::before {
    content: 'min-width: 768px | ';
  }
  .does-not-work {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="works">works</span>
<span class="does-not-work">does not work</span>
```

---

**Side note, based on comments:** About a year ago I had the same issue with a huge website. Result of a team of 6's work of nearly two years. Bits of code pouring in from all sides. I was the one gluing front-end together, making sure it all worked. You can imagine `@media` queries were a mess. I only got rid of the bug by refactoring all queries using mobile first principle - I grouped all `@media`'s using [Bootstrap's exact order](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries). Fixed it for me. To this day I don't know what caused it. It was (slightly) broken on (exactly) `768px` and `992px` before.

Comment: Thanks Andrei - that also works fine for me.  I'm guessing the problem is a combination of bootstrap plus Chrome similar to the github issue link I posted.  I can't replicate the issue without using bootstrap but it's difficult to share the whole thing with you without going through a lengthy process simplifying my project down into something that will be easy to understand on a fiddle

Comment: From what you describe it sounds more like it's a `typo` in your CSS files. Might be an un-closed `@media` query, missing semi-colon, could be from a number of reasons. The best thing you can do is create a new `stylesheet` and copy-paste chunks of existing CSS in it. You'll be able to pinpoint when you transfer the error and hopefully find it. Or you could use a validator, but that doesn't work every time. I personally rely on my `IDE`'s ability to warn me of any problems my code might have. Before you ask, I'm a dinosaur: I use `phpStorm`. `webStorm` is the modern counterpart - same company.

Comment: Thanks Andrei - I think I'll have to try that - one more thing to point out - if I change my setup so that I have a max-width:768px and min-width:768px the problem disappears in Chrome but I get the same thing in Safari and Firefox with styles not being applied at the breakpoint - pretty frustrating, but I think I'm going to have to spend some quality time going through all my css :|

Comment: About a year ago I had the same issue with a huge website. Result of a team of 6's work of nearly two years. Bits of code pouring in from all sides. I was the one gluing front-end/css together, making sure it all worked. You can imagine what a mess `@media` queries were. I only got rid of this by refactoring all queries using mobile first principle - I basically grouped all @media's using [Bootstrap's exact order](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries). Fixed it for me. To this day I don't know what caused it. :) - I'll add this to answer. Might be useful to others, just realized :)

Comment: Thanks again Andrei - just been a few hours of simplifying/troubleshooting and it actually seems to be (bizarrely) something specific to running on MAMP/local (which I can fix if I change the max-width and min-width to the same value).  Any ideas why that might be the case would be appreciated, but otherwise I'm going to just accept this as a glitch on my localhost only