# Bootstrap 3 hidden elements on half screen width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a strange error with Bootstrap 3, essentially when reducing my browser width to half screen, there is a tiny almost 1px threshold in which both hidden-xs and hidden-sm elements appear on the screen. Is there any way to rectify this by having either one of the hidden-xs or hidden-sm elements actually being hidden rather than both being displayed?

I have tested this on bootstrap's website example found here http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/css/ under helper classes > showing and hiding content

[Here is bootstrap's website example on half screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbjfq.png)

Once the screen width is reduced by a tiny amount from being half-width, the following is show (sorry I could only post one link):
✔ Hidden on x-small (Green)
Medium (Greyed out)
✔ Hidden on x-small and small (Green)
✔ Hidden on x-small and medium (Green)
✔ Hidden on x-small and large (Green)

```
<div class='col-xs-12'><div class='hidden-xs'>This content should be hidden on mobile only, but visible on everything else</div><div class='hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg'>This content should be hidden on everything apart from xs devices</div></div>
```

However, when the browser is reduced to half the screen's width, both the hidden-xs element and the hidden-sm, hidden-md hidden-lg element remain on screen until the width is either reduced or increased. (As if there was a gap in the width required to be an xs or sm element)

Comment: You can add part of your code here in a snippet . IT will show your issue and it will easier to get help from the SO users ;) Welcome

Comment: Hi, cheers. I didn't feel like it was necessary to add any code since I've found this to be an actual problem with Bootstrap itself rather than what I have coded, I'll quickly attach an example of the kind of problem that I'm facing.

Comment: After testing and researching some more... I found this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180675/bootstrap-layout-media-queries-not-working-at-767px-on-chrome, this is the exact same error, but I've tried the solutions (rearranging media queries, trying it on live websites, etc.) but I've still unfortunately got anywhere, has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

After messing around for a while, I've discovered a solution, but first, a better explanation of the problem is needed.

This problem exclusively occurs at the exact maximum width of each element size class e.g. xs, sm, etc. in Google Chrome only. Bootstrap developers are aware of this problem but for some reason are not prepared to act on it.

If you wish for hidden-xs and hidden-sm elements etc. to not be both displayed at the same time, you need to change each hidden class's media query's max-width to have more precision e.g. hidden-xs, hidden-sm etc. to be max-width: *.99;

I have provided an example below:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767.99px) {
    .hidden-xs {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.99px) {
    .hidden-sm {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.99px) {
    .hidden-md {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .hidden-lg {
        display: none;
    }
}
```